# representation of this argument in the complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers

> If $|z_1| =|z_2|$ and $\arg(z_1/z_2)=π $, then $z_1+z_2$ is

My attempt – We can represent $z_1$ and $z_2$ as two complex numbers at the same distances from origin in the Argand plane but I can't seem to represent the argument in the Argand plane. Can someone help me for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

The argument of a non-zero complex number corresponds to the `polar angle` of its affix in polar coordinates; and the argument of a quotient of complex numbers is the difference of their arguments.

Comment: arg(z1/z2)=arg z1-arg z2 ...this i know.But i am having comfusion in representing it in argand plane.Will the complex numbers lie diagonally opposite to each other or something like that.

Comment: What  does ,a rotation of π correspond to, geometrically, in your opinion?

Comment: for me,it's like the number is rotated π clockwise

Comment: That's right, but there's a still  simpler interpretation.

Comment: can u tell me about it

Comment: Central symmetry  w.r.t. origin.

Comment: So is my representation correct?

Comment: Yes, you you just messed to use the term ‘central symmetry’.

Comment: So will the complex numbers lie opposite to each other so as to satisfy the condition

Comment: It's exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to solve the problem. One way is to see that $$z_1+z_2 = z_2 \left(1+\frac{z_1}{z_2}\right).$$
Now, $\left|\frac{z_1}{z_2}\right|=1$ and $\arg\left(\frac{z_1}{z_2}\right)=\pi$ implies $\frac{z_1}{z_2}=\cos(\pi)+i \sin(\pi) = ? \implies z_1 + z_2 = ?$

Comment: i got your method  but can u help me representing the arguement (z1/z2) in complex plane.I want to solve this question using geometry